# Problem with c program to find the number of bits in a data type

Tags: c

I have an assignment to write code that find the max value that a certain data type can hold. I am doing this using the rolling 1 test by using a left shift. It is working fine for the int, char, short int, and long int, however i cannot get it to work for the unsigned in and unsigned char. The code runs, however when it gets to that point it just gets stuck and doesnt output anything. Ill attach my entire code below. How can I get this to work, what am I doing wrong. I made sure to use %u instead of %d, im not sure what else i would have to change. Thank you!!

```
//
//  File name: ewh9320_proj2_data_types_rotate.c
//  Author: Ethan Hall
//  Created for RIT CMPR271 on 9/25/19
//  Purpose: To find the maximum value of bits used for each data type
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    //int
    int overflow0, previous0;
    while(1)
    {
        previous0 = overflow0;
        overflow0 = 1 + (previous0<<1);
        if(previous0 > overflow0)
        {
            printf("int:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous0);
            break;
        }
    }

    //char
    char overflow1, previous1;
    while(1)
    {
        previous1 = overflow1;
        overflow1 = 1 + (previous1<<1);
        if(previous1 > overflow1)
        {
            printf("char:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous1);
            break;
        }
    }

    //short int
    short int overflow2, previous2;
    while(1)
    {
        previous2 = overflow2;
        overflow2 = 1 + (previous2<<1);
        if(previous2 > overflow2)
        {
            printf("short int:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous2);
            break;
        }
    }

    //unsigned int
    unsigned int overflow3, previous3;
    while(1)
    {
        previous3 = overflow3;
        overflow3 = 1 + (previous3<<1);
        if(previous3 > overflow3)
        {
            printf("unsigned int:\n");
            printf("The max value is %u\n\n", previous3);
            break;
        }
    }

    //unsigned char
    unsigned char overflow4, previous4;
    while(1)
    {
        previous4 = overflow4;
        overflow4 = 1 + (previous4<<1);
        if(previous4 > overflow4)
        {
            printf("unsigned char:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous4);
            break;
        }
    }

    //long int
    long int overflow5, previous5;
    while(1)
    {
        previous5 = overflow5;
        overflow5 = 1 + (previous5<<1);
        if(previous5 > overflow5)
        {
            printf("long int:\n");
            printf("The max value is %ld\n\n", previous5);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

second program that wont run past int64_t:

```
int main(void)
{
    //int8_t
    int8_t overflow0, previous0;
    while(1)
    {
        previous0 = overflow0;
        overflow0 = 1 + (previous0<<1);
        if(previous0 > overflow0)
        {
            printf("int8_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous0);
            break;
        }
    }

    //uint8_t
    uint8_t overflow1, previous1;
    while(1)
    {
        previous1 = overflow1;
        overflow1 = 1 + (previous1<<1);
        if(previous1 > overflow1)
        {
            printf("uint8_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %u\n\n", previous1);
            break;
        }
    }

    //int16_t
    int16_t overflow2, previous2;
    while(1)
    {
        previous2 = overflow2;
        overflow2 = 1 + (previous2<<1);
        if(previous2 > overflow2)
        {
            printf("int16_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous2);
            break;
        }
    }

    //uint16_t
    uint16_t overflow3, previous3;
    while(1)
    {
        previous3 = overflow3;
        overflow3 = 1 + (previous3<<1);
        if(previous3 > overflow3)
        {
            printf("uint16_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %u\n\n", previous3);
            break;
        }
    }

    //int32_t
    int32_t overflow4, previous4;
    while(1)
    {
        previous4 = overflow4;
        overflow4 = 1 + (previous4<<1);
        if(previous4 > overflow4)
        {
            printf("int32_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %d\n\n", previous4);
            break;
        }
    }


    //uint32_t
    uint32_t overflow5, previous5;
    while(1)
    {
        previous5 = overflow5;
        overflow5 = 1 + (previous5<<1);
        if(previous5 > overflow5)
        {
            printf("uint32_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %u\n\n", previous5);
            break;
        }
    }

    //int64_t
    int64_t overflow6, previous6;
    while(1)
    {
        previous6 = overflow6;
        overflow6 = 1 + (previous6<<1);
        if(previous6 >= overflow6)
        {
            printf("int64_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %lld\n\n", previous6);
            break;
        }
    }

    //uint64_t
    uint64_t overflow7, previous7;
    while(1)
    {
        previous7 = overflow7;
        overflow7 = 1 + (previous7<<1);
        if(previous7 > overflow7)
        {
            printf("uint64_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %llu\n\n", previous7);
            break;
        }
    }

    //uintptr_t
    uintptr_t overflow8, previous8;
    while(1)
    {
        previous8 = overflow8;
        overflow8 = 1 + (previous8<<1);
        if(previous8 > overflow8)
        {
            printf("uintptr_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %lu\n\n", previous8);
            break;
        }
    }

    //intmax_t
    intmax_t overflow9, previous9;
    while(1)
    {
        previous9 = overflow9;
        overflow9 = 1 + (previous9<<1);
        if(previous9 > overflow9)
        {
            printf("intmax_t:\n");
            printf("The max value is %ld\n\n", previous9);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `unsigned char` loop, put a `printf("%u %u\n", previous4, overflow4)` before the `if` statement and see what you get.

Comment: "It is working fine for the int, ..., short int, and long int," --> code replies on signed integer overflow which is _undefined behavior_, `UB.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that by putting a >= in my if statement it solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: however i am having another issue with a related program. THis uses the same method of rolling 1 left shift to find the max value for a data type, however uses differnt data types. It has no problem getting through the unsigned types, however once it hits int64_t, it gets stuck. Ive added the code to the first post